# Managed MySQL cluster - similar solution for a private cloud

Tags: kubernetes, mysql, vmware

Is it possible to build a similar solution to managed MySQL cluster on a private cloud (VMware vSphere / Hyper V). Even with Kubernetes.
A solution which supports auto-scaling, auto-upgrade, multi-master and similar to the largest public clouds offerings.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any reason why you can't.  I think that the issue would be in getting the memory management correct on the host.  The orchestration would be the same.

Here's some resources:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-cluster-excerpt/8.0/en/faqs-mysql-cluster.html#qandaitem-B-1-13
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-multi-node-mysql-cluster-on-ubuntu-18-04.  It shows with docker as well. it shouldn't be hard to apply to vmware or k8s.
- https://towardsdatascience.com/high-availability-mysql-cluster-with-load-balancing-using-haproxy-and-heartbeat-40a16e134691/
- https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/orchestrate-a-local-cluster-with-kubernetes.html to set up k8s locally.

Comment: How is it possible to scale it automatically when it's deployed on VMs, without Kuberentes? Let's say scale up depending on a metric such as CPU usage

Comment: I'm not sure what you use for tools, but I'd use Ansible/Chef/etc. to set up the replication to add or remove slaves as necessary.  Have a role/recipe to spin up a new VM, another to introduce the VM into the cluster and a third to adjust the load-balance to introduce the node.  How this is triggered depends on the monitoring system to detect the load.